# Input Image to U Net with Pretrained ResNet34 Encoder

Tags: conv-neural-network, image-processing, transfer-learning

Most of the pretrained architecture accept the input image size 224x224, but do we have to always resize our images to 224x224?

I try to do both resize 224x224 and 512x512, the first resolution give lousy image quality, while the second image resolution had a better image quality (my original image size is 4288x2488). Because it's segmentation task, I think that the 224x224 quality can affect the segmentation results because the image quality is not clear enough so that the segmented part is not clear either.

So do we have to resize the image to 224x224 for following the pretrained rules or not?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.